# NHibernate & WCF: Performance (session reuse) vs. concurrency (simultaneous requests)

Tags: wcf, performance, nhibernate, concurrency, sessionfactory

We are working on different integrations to a swarm of identically structured legacy databases that basically cannot be altered. For this, we added an auxiliary database for holding things like meta-information, routing rules and for temporarily holding data for the legacy databases.

We are mainly using NHibernate to connect to the databases. One application is a WCF Service that needs to inserts incoming data into nested tables that are really wide (dozens of columns). Obviously, performance is an issue, so I have been looking to be as economic as possible with the NHibernate transactions. At the same time, concurrency appeared to be an issue. In production, we were starting to get some zombied transaction errors (deadlocks).

I have been doing a balancing act to deal with these two issues but haven't really eliminated the concurrency problems.

The service behaviour is set to handle one request at a time, like so:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall, ConcurrencyMode=ConcurrencyMode.Single]
public class LegacyGateService : ILegacyGateService
```

Earlier, after some "inspiration" (read: copy/paste) from the internet, I ended up adding a set of classes called something like XxxNHibernateUtil, for the auxiliary database and the legacy databases, respectively. These classes control the NHibernate Sessions and generate or re-use the Sessions from pre-initialized SessionFactories.

For the Auxiliary database it looks like this:

```
public static class LegacyGateNHibernateUtil
{
    private static readonly ISessionFactory sessionFactory = BuildSessionFactory();

    private static ISessionFactory BuildSessionFactory()
    {
        try
        {
            Configuration Cfg = new Configuration();
            Cfg.Configure();
            Cfg.AddAssembly("LegacyGate.Persistence");
            return Cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    public static ISessionFactory GetSessionFactory()
    {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

    public static ISession GetCurrentSession()
    {
        if (!CurrentSessionContext.HasBind(GetSessionFactory()))
            CurrentSessionContext.Bind(GetSessionFactory().OpenSession());

        return GetSessionFactory().GetCurrentSession();
    }

    public static void DisposeCurrentSession()
    {
        ISession currentSession = CurrentSessionContext.Unbind(GetSessionFactory());

        if (currentSession != null)
        {
            if (currentSession.IsOpen)
                currentSession.Close();
            currentSession.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Whenever a session is needed for a transaction, the current session is looked up and re-used for the duration of the service request call. Or at least: That is what is supposed to be happening.

**EDIT:** The session context is of course set in the hibernate.cfg.xml like so:

```
  <property name="current_session_context_class">call</property>
```

For the legacy databases, the NHibernateUtil is adapted to deal with different possible databases. For this, each connection gets its own SessionFactory built that has to be looked up in a Dictionary collection. Otherwise, the principles are the same.

Testing using WCFStorm, this seems to be working fine when sending one request at a time, but as soon I start a load test, even with just one agent and long intervals, I get a plethora of different kinds of exceptions all pointing to simultaneous requests and transactions sabotaging each other. I have tried tweaking the IsolationLevel, but of now avail.

I think I need to generate and handle Sessions in a different way, so that different  transactions to the same databases are handled in an orderly fashion and not interfere with each other. However, I lack some insight in how to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

---

**EDIT** For one service method, when testing with more than one agent, the first dozen or so call work fine, and then the following string of exceptions start appearing that only pertain the auxiliary database:

1. "There was a problem converting an IDataReader to NDataReader" /
   "Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed."
2. "illegal access to loading collection"
3. "Begin failed with SQL exception" / "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
4. "could not execute query" / "ExecuteReader requires an open and available Connection. The connection's current state is closed."
5. "could not initialize a collection:" / "Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding."
6. "Transaction not successfully started"
7. "The transaction is either not associated with the current connection or has been completed."
8. "could not initialize a collection:" / "Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed."

Exception 1, at least, indicates that the same session is accessed by multiple threads (calls probably). Also the other ones indicate that the current session is interrupted by other processes. But how can this be, when I tried to isolate the calls and have them queued up?

For another service method, these issues do not appear with the auxiliary database, but after some time I start getting the ZombiedTransaction exceptions (deadlocks) with transactions to the legacy databases. Still... What gives?

Comment: It does sound like you are running into concurrency issues.  What version of NH are you using?  If you are using 3.2 I would suggest using "wcf_operation" as your session context.  If you are not using 3.2 there is still an easy way you can do this.

Comment: Also the statement `throw ex;` above is a big no-no.  You're destroying the stack trace when you do that. You should use `throw;` Since you aren't doing anything with the exception there shouldn't even be a try catch block.

Comment: Sorry. I overlooked your comments. I am using version 3.1, but I could upgrade in a snap, if that would help! :-) 
And OK, I will fix my exception no-no's and keep this in mind for the future! 
Thnx so far!

Comment: Done the upgrade to 3.2, but the download didn't include the Castle ByteCode assembly. I used the one from 3.1, but it is not being recognized/found when I run the application. I get a "Unable to load type 'NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle.ProxyFactoryFactory, NHibernate.ByteCode.Castle'". ???

Comment: It looks like I don't need it any more, so I will remove all references to Castle.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The easy answer: **You don't re-use NHibernate sessions.**

They're not heavyweight objects and they are designed to be created, manipulated and disposed following the Unit of Work pattern. **Attempting to "share" these across multiple requests goes against their intended usage.**

Fundamentally, the cost of synchronizing access to the sessions correctly will almost certainly negate any benefit you gain by recycling them to avoid re-initializing them. Let's also consider that these costs are a drop in the pond of the SQL you'll be executing.

Remember that NHibernate's Session Factory is the heavyweight object. It's thread-safe, so you can and should share a single instance across all requests out of the box.

Your code should look conceptually like this:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    static Service()
    {
        Configuration Cfg = new Configuration();
        Cfg.Configure();
        Cfg.AddAssembly("LegacyGate.Persistence");
        Service.SessionFactory = Cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
    }

    protected static ISessionFactory SessionFactory { get; private set; }

    public void ServiceMethod(...)
    {
        using(var session = Service.SessionFactory.CreateSession())
        {
            // Do database stuff
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

As an aside: Ideally, you'd be dependency-injecting the `ISessionFactory` into the service.

Comment: Might also be worth noting that the NHibernate session is used for entity tracking, which might cause behaviour that looks like memory leaks if you use the same session for a long time (i.e. all entities in the database might end up being tracked by the session).

Comment: Hmmm... Good point! So basically change the GetCurrentSession-method to just one line: return GetSessionFactory().OpenSession(); ?

Comment: But will this eliminate the deadlocks too?

Comment: I think that is a bad idea @FedorSteeman unless you are implementing `using` blocks around each call to `GetCurrentSession`.  If it were me I would investigate if session sharing is really going on across threads which it sounds like it is and figure out how to fix it before you take the "easy" way out.  Did you try my suggestion above?

Comment: @ColeW: OK. However, perhaps I could do this for the Auxiliary only and not for the legacy databases, where the deadlocks are occurring. I will in any case upgrade to 3.2 asap and report back.

Comment: I can't upvote this enough. Do not reuse sessions -- since a stateful session is conceptually an unit of work, you'll basically be hanging on to every entity you've ever loaded through it, not to mention a bunch of other crap as well (including but not limited to copies of the values in each field, for change tracking). You do not gain performance by reusing sessions.

Comment: All right. I am now no longer re-using Sessions, and it has eliminated almost all concurrency problems mentioned, except one: The zombied transactions keep on occurring whenever I crank up the stress high enough. I reckon database transactions still take too long, causing deadlocks. Anyway, will mark this as answer, as it led me back on the right track.

Comment: @ColeW When doing some refactoring I discovered some left-over code that actually caused a lot of the concurrency errors I mentioned. So you were right on not choosing the easy way out and finding out what was going wrong first! Something WAS lurking behind it all...